# Images tags not showing in wicked_pdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

I have a rails app, in which i store some images in AWS, and show them in a PDF report. When there is no images to be shown, i show a placeholder, like this one here: [image].

The problem is: the image is not show in the PDF file. When in debug mode, the image is shown as usual, but never in my PDF! The link to the image is like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4096865/missing.png

Edit 1:

I tried to include the image like this: `image_tag("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4096865/missing.png")`

The solution i've found was simple, but prevented me from using dropbox for storage: it must be a http url. So, when i uploaded it to AWS S3, it worked!

So, this here works perfectly: `image_tag("http://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/base-fisc-prod/missing.png")`

Comment: Can you paste he the code that your using for including the image

Comment: can you just simply try this and check if you get the image `image_tag("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4096865/missing.png")`

Comment: @AnantKolvankar i've pasted now, an as you can read there, it just didn't work because of the HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with images stored in a HTTPS link, the easiest way to solve this is to store the images in a HTTP link.

If you must store them in HTTPS, use this solution provided [here](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/36#issuecomment-91027880)

Comment: Yes, i've spent about two hours trying to solve this, so i've asked question and answer, so that other people find this before they spend two hours of work.

Comment: You can safely accept your own answer as a correct one ;).

Comment: @adamliesko i still have to wait untill tomorow to be able to do that! :)